~1980 UK TV: very intelligent children recruited for secret project
I'm trying to remember a TV series in the UK some time around 1980. It was aimed at 10-15 year olds.
A shadowy organisation was recruiting very intelligent children for some kind of project. The protagonist was found after breaking in to his school computer room to use the Commodore PET computer. The children were taken to a manor house where they were given difficult maths research problems. There was some kind of mind-control element called "The Game" involving an empty room and, at one point, the sound of seagulls.

It's not Whiz Kids (1984)

https://starringthecomputer.com/computer.html?c=178 - Whiz KIds (1983) fits some of these tropes

Have you ruled out all the other TV shows on that list?

Possibly one of the sequels to Chocky? I think Chocky's Children involved young people working on problems in a manor house.

@DanielRoseman no, not that either.

Codename Icarus

The first of the main plot strands follows Martin Smith (Barry Angel), a pupil at a Northern comprehensive who appears at first to be the class clown. But Martin, who cheats at maths and is often in detention, is actually bored and frustrated by the simplicity of his schoolwork. After hours, he sneaks into the sixth form computer room to work on maths and physics problems that are advanced even for degree level. Martin, it turns out, is a child prodigy.
https://www.the-medium-is-not-enough.com/2010/02/lost_gems_codename_icarus_1981.php

He is taken to a special school for geniuses and there they play 'the Game' in a squash court.
Available on youtube at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL90A6A12B169D1847
